# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is not working when tabbarcontroller-viewcontroller's are embedded in navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

My app ui heirarchy look like as shown. UItabbarcontroller -> navigation-controllers -> view-controllers.

[image]

The problem am facing is hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is not working when i try to push a new controller from 1st Vc on button click

```
if let newVc = UIStoryboard.homeSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: NewViewController.identifier()) as? NewViewController{
    self.navigationController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewAllVc, animated: true)
}
```

The Tabbar is still showing in the NewVc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the tab bar in new VC you can call this in viewDidLoad():

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Also, you should call method hidesBottomBarWhenPushed from your VC, not from the navigation controller:

```
if let newVc = UIStoryboard.homeSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: NewViewController.identifier()) as? NewViewController{
newVc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewAllVc, animated: true) 
}
```

Furthermore, you can make it on your new VC storyboard:

[image]

[hidesBottomBarWhenPushed in developer.apple.com/documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed)

Answer (score 2):

//use this method in the view controller where you want to hide tabBar

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        return navigationController?.topViewController == self
    }
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work even if `get` always returns `true`. Found out that this property works when you call `pushViewController` with animation only

Answer (score 0):

add these codes in your navigationbar.swift

```
 override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if children.count > 0 {
            viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        }
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
```